# instancemethod object is unsubscriptable for in_ method

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-2.5

I have the following code

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://test:password@localhost/test")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.bind = engine
table = Table('test_table', metadata, autoload = True)
a = session.query(table).filter(table.c.id.in_['1', '2'])
```

This is the error that is encountered.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is unsubscriptable
```

I am sure that it is something i am doing wrong because I am new to python. Thank you in advance (I am pretty sure it is a rookie mistake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ColumnOperators.in_](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_) is a function, and therefore must be called. Following should work:

```
a = session.query(table).filter(table.c.id.in_(['1', '2']))
```

Comment: i was pretty sure it was a rookie mistake . thanks for the fast reply :)